# Why Manage_fields and Manage_display tab are not shown in content type?

Tags: 7, entities

Suddenly My dev site is not showing

> Manage_fields and Manage_displays

in all content types. I am using contributed module admin_menu. I clear all cache but it happens same. This is multilingual site. I can't understand why it occurs? Can anyone solve this problem? I have enabled field_ui modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unchecked permission of field. After checked it shows the tabs. Make sure two things to solve this problem.
1. Enable Field UI (field_ui) module
2. Make sure the field in permission is checked

> admin > people > permissions